# Many threads query in Hibernate. org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an application where I'm creating many threads. They have an attribute with the session to query (which has been configured previously).

When I try to query, I got this exception:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction

I have been reading that session, session can't be shared between threads, I would like to know what the best way to fix this. Can I only open a new connection for each thread??

```
  public Configuration get(final String id) {
            final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); //it works with openSession..
            final Configuration object =
                    (Configuration) session.get(Configuration.class.getName(),
                            id);
            return object;
        }


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                    <!-- <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>--> 
                    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>

                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">125</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">500</prop>
                </props>
            </property>



<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="com.pragsis.bidoop.data.tx.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="txTemplate" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="get*">
                PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED,readOnly
            </prop>
            <prop key="list*">
                PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED,readOnly
            </prop>
            <prop key="*">
                PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have marked the method that I use on the threads like transactional, The service, not the get method from Configuration but, I get the same error.

I'm using Spring for managing transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Every transaction is thread-bound so if you span a new Thread it won't have access to the originating Thread's transaction.

The most simple solution is to call @Transactional services from your newly created Thread:

```
myService.getSomething();
```

When such @Transactional service method is called a new Transaction is associated to the current thread and since you use Spring then all your DAOs will use it accordingly.

Comment: I opened again the connection in the run method for each thread and it worked. Although I didn't get to work when I do it in a webv application with Tomcat6.

Comment: Every new thread will have its own transaction in its own connection. You're right with that.